# How to calculate number of specific sized areas in a polygon

Tags: polygon, arcgis

During my investigation I have been trying to find out appropriate locations for a proposed wind turbine development, through this I have calculated suitable areas as shown in Figure 1. But I am still trying to find a way to calculate the number of turbines which could be situated inside of this polygon, as the turbines cannot be built within 6 diameters of each other, a buffer zone of 765.6 meters will be required.

Is there a tool to calculate the number which could theoretically fit inside, with the buffer zones able to pass over the edge of the polygons? An example is shown in Figure 1, but I was hoping to do this accurately in ArcGIS

[image: Figure 1. Showing suitable area for development and example duffer zones around turbines]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Create Random Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm): use your polgyon feature class as the constraining field, and then set the Allowed Minimum Distance to 765.6 meters, then set the number of points to a ridiculously high number per polygon to ensure that as many points can fit, are fit. This would generate points within the polygons and at a minimum distance to meet the requirements specified. Additionally, using [Aggregate Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/feature-analysis/aggregate-points.htm) will give you information on how many points are in each polygon. It's not the cleanest way to accomplish this, but it will get the job done.

P.S. I only just realized this question is 4 years old. Oh well, perhaps someone else can benefit from the answer!